# How do I align one div to another in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following html. My `label` is not aligned vertically in the center compare to the `input` field.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label for="investmentbalance" class="control-label pull-right">Investment Balance</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="28500.00" class="form-control" name="investmentbalance" id="investmentbalance">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I set both `input` and `label` have the same height ?

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/mLcrv19z/

Comment: you may use margin-top

Comment: You're going to need to create some extra column counts there. A row should have 12 allocated columns; currently you've got 7 (5+2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the two elements (label and input) to align vertically, try using the `form-inline` class, along with `form-group`. Here's what that looks like:

```
<div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="investmentbalance">Investment Balance</label>
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="28500.00" class="form-control" name="investmentbalance" id="investmentbalance" />
        </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mLcrv19z/10/

Answer (score 2):

You can use both [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) or [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).

Add to `label`:

```
padding: 7px;
```

or:

```
line-height: 34px;
```

The input height is 20px; the padding 6 and the margin 1. So here's the calculation:

**padding**: 6 + 1 = 7px

**line-height**: 20 + 7 (top) + 7 (bottom) = 34px

Answer (score 1):

You may use `margin-top:3%;` to the `label` CSS

The value is based on the jsfiddle example. It may change depending on the application you are developing.

Comment: it'd be better to provide general purpose answers

Answer (score 1):

Issue is not with your alignment but the classes you have defined. You need to define `bootstrap grid` class for every width. Otherwise grid would appear different in different resolutions. Check this out.

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xs-10">

<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2">
```

Fiddle [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/mLcrv19z/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use a custom class, setting it's line-height equal to the parent's height and aligning it in the middle.

```css
.middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row middle">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="investmentbalance" class="control-label pull-right">Investment Balance</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="28500.00" class="form-control" name="investmentbalance" id="investmentbalance">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```